# How to create a flutter plugin that opens the app from a closed state when a background service event is fired

Tags: android, plugins, flutter

I'm creating a flutter plugin based on the quick_actions flutter plugin, this plugin adds app shortcuts to the android app and will launch the app at a certain page when clicked. This only works when the app is already opened and running in the background. Trying to open the page without the app open results in a blank xml page with the app name in the scaffold title. Trying to figure out how to use the plugin to open the flutter app instead of this blank android one

**app closed:**

[image: appClosed]

**available actions:**

[image: availableActions]

**result when clicked:**

[image: resultWhenClicked]

**app open in background:**

[image: appOpenInBackground]

**result when clicked:**

[image: resultWhenClicked]

Comment: Please share code